# Find the integers in an array which are bigger than all the elements to the right

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to write a JS function which finds all the top integers, a top integer is an integer  which is bigger than all the elements to its right. This is how far I've gotten:

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/zehiyidupu/1/embed?js,console)

```
function testArray(array) {
  var copy = [...array],
    result = [],
    number = [];
  copy.forEach(function(el, i, ar) {
    let sliced = array.slice(i);
    console.log(sliced);
    //     number.push(sliced[0]);
    number = [sliced[0]];
    console.log(number);
    for (let y = i; y <= sliced.length - 1; y++) {
      //       console.log(sliced,'sliced array')
      console.log(sliced[y], 'for-loop currentValue')

      //       let newArray = sliced.filter(function(el,i,ar){
      //         return el < sliced[0];
      //         console.log(sliced[0]);
      //         console.log(el);
      //         console.log(ar);
      //         if (sliced[0] > el) {
      //           numbers.push(sliced[0]);
      //         }
      //       });
    }
  })
  //   console.log(newArray);
}

var arr1 = [1, 4, 3, 2]; //--> 4,3,2
var arr2 = [14, 24, 3, 19, 15, 17]; //--> 24,19,17
var arr3 = [41, 41, 34, 20]; //--> 41,34,24
var arr4 = [27, 19, 42, 2, 13, 45, 48]; //--> 48
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/favukutase/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `slice()` and `Math.max()`. And if `17` is **top integer** in `arr2`. then `48` should be top too in `arr4`. My function returns array. You can print all of the array.

```js
var arr1 = [1,4,3,2];                   //--> 4,3,2
var arr2 = [14, 24, 3, 19, 15, 17];     //--> 24,19,17
var arr3 = [41, 41, 34, 20];            //--> 41,34,24
var arr4 = [27, 19, 42, 2, 13, 45, 48];
function topInts(arr){
  const tops = [];
  arr.forEach((item,i) => {
    if(Math.max(...arr.slice(i)) === item) tops.push(item);
  })
  console.log([...new Set(tops)]);
} 
topInts(arr1);   // [4,3,2]
topInts(arr2);   // [24,19,17]
topInts(arr3);   // [41,34,24]
topInts(arr4);   // [48]
```